# Do I need to use base64 for sending a video over UDP?

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, udp

I am trying out UDP and TCP and while browsing for sending real-time video, like screen-capture(this is for a basic screen sharing project) over UDP I saw that each frame is being encoded to base64 before being sent over UDP. From what I read base64 for video streaming is bad and I wanted to use h.264/vp9 encoding for video but I couldn't figure out how.

So, is there anyway that I can achieve this, or is base64 the only way for UDP communication?

I used python and socket for trying this out.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am trying to achieve low latency for uses like cloud gaming, in this project, so any recommendation towards that would be wonderful too!

Comment: There is no requirement or benefit to base64 encoding data for transmission over UDP.

Comment: Hey! Thank you for the reply! But whenever I try to pass something else to a socket in python I encounter an error saying "socket expects bytes". Could you please tell me how to overcome this? @PresidentJamesK.Polk